# JavaScript + MySql?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Я хотел спросить, можно ли через javascript работать с БД mysql?

То есть в php есть стандартные функции для работы с базами mysql, а в javascript я таких не замечал.

Например: у меня есть submit форма, в которой пользователь ввел какую-нибудь информацию (логин например), и мне нужно проверить есть ли такой логин в БД. И нужно чтоб если такой логин уже есть в БД то сразу появлялась надпись что "Такой логин уже зарегистрирован".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AJAX в помощь. На сервере делаете на том же РНР обёртки к функциям базы данных (с соответствующими запретами и проверкой всего, чего только можно, чтоб в базе ничего не наделали) и делаете запросы к нему из JS.

Статей на эту тему очень много в интернете =) И примеров.

```
JS (AJAX) -> PHP: есть в базе 'Вася'?
PHP: Угу, вопрос нормальный, палева нет, сейчас спрошу у информбюро.
PHP -> MySQL: 'Васю' знаешь?
MySQL -> PHP: угу
PHP -> JS: да, пусть пробует другой логин, ибо второго Васи на не надобно.
```

Comment: так и безопаснее - не надо раскрывать логин и пароль доступа к Mysql.

Comment: А можно какой-нибуть пример этой функции?

Comment: Первый попавшийся пример из гугля: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Милый пример! :)

Comment: данный пример вызвал у меня широчайшую улыбку на все 64 ))! зато капец как понятно )