# JavaScript + MySql?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Нужна случайная выборка текста из базы через javascript из mysql БД, не обращаясь при этом к поднятию сервера с последующим пхп.

Есть ли какие-нибудь стандартные функции?

Comment: Зачем? Вкратце - что именно вы реализовываете? (это нужно для того, что-бы можно было дать вразумительный ответ)

Comment: хотим реализовать через PhoneGap  мобильное приложение на андроид.это что-то типа тестника с вопросами и выбором ответа.вот как прикрутить базу?

Comment: ИМХО - есть 2 варианта которые не противоречат kiss:

a) сервер

б) все данные хранить прямо в коде

В случае если вопросы не будут изменятся ( либо будут изменятся редко ) я бы выбрал второе, в том случае, если вопросы будут пополнятся - написал-бы сервер.

Вообще с т.з. безопасности - прямое подключение с БД, мягко говоря, не является лучшим решением, более того - прямых средств для этого, скорее всего попросту нет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JavaScript + MySql?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16318/javascript-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

есть 2 варианта которые не противоречат [kiss](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)):

1. сервер
2. все данные хранить прямо в коде

В случае если, вопросы не будут изменяться (либо будут изменяться редко), я бы выбрал второе.

В том случае, если вопросы будут пополняться - написал бы сервер.

Вообще с точки зрения безопасности - прямое подключение к БД, мягко говоря, не является лучшим решением, более того - прямых средств для этого скорее всего попросту нет.

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае MySQL будет крутиться на сервере, так что сервер есть.
Если очень хочется остаться в рамках JS - Node.JS в помощь, крутите на сервере, пусть оно выполняет запросы и отдаёт ответы в том же Json. Будет шустренько.

В этом случае как минимум не потребуется во всех экземплярах приложения хранить логин/пароль для подключения.

Второй вариант - SQLite. Локальный файл на смартфоне, дальше творите что хотите. Обновление базы вопросов - скачивание нового файла.

Comment: mysql может крутиться и локально и без сервера, только смысла в этом нет, да )

Comment: ну тут проблема в том, что целевое приложение 4 года назад планировалось крутить на андроиде, а тащить Mysql на андроид несколько странно

Answer (score 0):

Без сервера сделать обращение к БД не возможно. JavaScript работает в браузере, браузер отсылает запросы на веб сервер, веб сервер отдает этот запрос интерпретатору например php (или любой другой серверное технологии), и уже только после этого в серверном скрипте можно обращаться к бд. Потом все в обратом порядке из БД данные возвращаются в скрипт, из скрипта в веб сервер, из веб сервера в браузер. 
Обратиться к БД через JS с браузера минуя сервер  нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

В современных браузерах есть noSQL [база данных встроенная](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/). 
Но с mysql без поднятия сервера хотябы локально у вас не получится никак (node.js это тоже поднятие сервера).