# Соединение с внешним mysql из браузера на javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, websocket

Как подключиться к серверу MySQL из браузера с помощью javascript?

Узнал, что надо копать в сторону WebSocket или raw socket, но информации об этом не нахожу.

С чего хотя бы начать?

Это не дубликат, так как автору другого вопроса подошел вариант через мост PHP. Мне не подходит.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [JavaScript + MySql?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16318/javascript-mysql)

Comment: Чем не подходит вариант работы через серверные скрипты?

Comment: Смотрите ниже..

Answer (score 2):

WebSocket вам не поможет. raw socket - это ближе к делу. Но по сути вам надо будет реализовать клиента mysql. Протокол там бинарный и вполне допускаю что возможно это сделать. Но в любом случае количество нужных для этого человекомесяцев заставляется задуматься: "А зачем?"

За бортом можно оставить и вопрос безопастности - так как это JavaScript - то узнать параметры подключения к вашему серверу - это будет дело пяти-десяти минут.

Поэтому я рекомендовал бы начать с использования серверного языка программирования - для создания скриптов, с которыми ваше приложение на javascript сможет взаимодействовать через WebSocket или через AJAX.

Comment: Разверние, пожалуйста, ответ по raw socket. Где? Как? Естественно, я знаю про CRUD, RPC, REST и пр. приблуды, это не подходит. Кратко: есть некий теоретический редактор на javascript, он очень любезен и хочет предоставить пользователю автозавершение и выбор таблиц и полей. Чтобы это осуществить, он запрашивает данные доступа к БД. Это может быть localhost@root, например. Вопрос безопасности - это только вопрос доверия пользователя. На счет человеко-часов: возможно, тот минимум, что мне необходим, и не требует таких уж серьезных ресурсов.

Comment: Разворачивать особо нечего - находите исходники клиентской библиотеки для MySQL и переписываете их на javascript.

Comment: API для raw socket не нахожу, вот в чем дело. например, есть спецификация: https://www.w3.org/2012/sysapps/tcp-udp-sockets/ , но в лисе она не работает.

Comment: @Mik, а это другой момент в том что это реализуемо пока только теоретически.

Comment: Т. е. html5 rawsocket пока существует только в умах?)

Comment: @Mik в хроме в виде экспериментального АПИ вроде бы как есть.

Comment: увы, это только для расширений. В консоли эти фичи недоступны.

Comment: @Mik Не заморачивайтесь в поиске raw socket. Все равно написание собственной библиотеки работающей по внутреннему протоколу mysql на js не стоит практически никаких преследуемых целей. Тем более, что от версии к версии mysql протоколы могут меняться и вы будете вынуждены следить за развитием mysql и выпускать новые версии "драйверов БД", предварительно написав код для всех в данный момент существующих версий